# How to kill two or more processes with one kill command?

Tags: shell-script, process, kill

I am using the following command to kill one java process via shell script:

> pidof java|xargs kill -9 $1

What if the list of `pidof` output has more than one elements? How do I kill them both with the same one command?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, check out `pkill`. You can kill off any number of process given their name:

```
pkill java
```

You can even use the full command with arguments as part of the search

```
pkill -f some_string_in_arguemnts
```

Secondly, your construct with `xargs` will work just fine for multiple PID's as long as they are piped in as either space or newline separated numbers.

Comment: +1: Thanks for fast answer. `Kill` with several process ids seems to be the best suitable solution for my purposes.

Comment: These utils (pkill, pgrep, pfind) aren't available on MacOS (at least not 10.5.x). If you're using MacPorts, the `proctools` package supplies them.

Answer (score 5):

The `killall` command is available on most Linuces at any rate.  You might have to install it on some distributions.  It allows you to kill all processes that match the name provided on the command line.

Comment: But beware if you are on a different system. Standard (non-GNU) killall does just that: it kills all processes (especially effective when executed by root). I've managed to bring down a Solaris and a Digital machine in this way when my fingers worked faster than my brain.

Answer (score 3):

`pgrep` can give you the list of PIDs

For example:

```
pgrep java
```

will give you the list of PIDs related to java. So you can use:

```
kill -9 `pgrep java`
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer

```
kill -9 `pidof java`
```

because of the inline output

```
> pgrep gulp
6316
6565
> pidof gulp
6565 6316
```

The problem with `pkill`, well you don't have it installed by default on some systems (like Ubuntu)